# How to set bar width using achartengine. My last bar is Squeezed out

Tags: android, width, bar-chart, achartengine

I have a barchart with 3 bars shown. Three bars displayed with different widths. How to set equal width to all bars?

This is the snapshot of my barchart

[image]

Please any one suggest!!

Any Help will be Appreciated!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have 2 series of data. One series has 2 items in it and the green one has only one item. When you have only one item in the series, it may make sense to set the bar width using:

```
renderer.setBarWidth(width);
```

Another solution is to add at least two items to your series.

Comment: It says that "The method setBarWidth(int) is undefined for the type XYMultipleSeriesRenderer" .

Comment: Use a recent version. https://repository-achartengine.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot/org/achartengine/achartengine/1.1.0/

Comment: thanks Dan even it helped me ... is there any API to set different colors for different height valve of single series???

Answer (score -1):

```
@SuppressLint("ParserError")
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private GraphicalView BarChartView;




    @SuppressLint("ParserError")
    @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (BarChartView==null )
        {

        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = buildBarRenderer();
        setChartSettings(renderer);
        BarChartView  = ChartFactory.getBarChartView(this, getBarDataset(), renderer, Type.DEFAULT);
        LinearLayout playout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.graph2);
        playout.addView(BarChartView);
        ;

        }
        else
        {

            BarChartView.repaint();
            BarChartView.setVisibility(View.GONE);


        }
    }

    private void setChartSettings(XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer)
    {
      renderer.setYTitle("Hits");
      renderer.setXAxisMin(0);
      renderer.setXAxisMax(7);
      renderer.setYAxisMin(0);
      renderer.setYAxisMax(900);

      }
    private XYMultipleSeriesDataset getBarDataset()
    {
            int[] y = {624,430,712};
            XYSeries series1 = new XYSeries("A");
            XYSeries series2 = new XYSeries("B");
            XYSeries series3 = new XYSeries("C");



            XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();


                    series1.add(1,y[0]);
                    dataset.addSeries(series1);

                    series2.add(2,y[1]);
                    dataset.addSeries(series2);

                    series3.add(3,y[2]);
                    dataset.addSeries(series3);



              return dataset;

    }
    protected XYMultipleSeriesRenderer buildBarRenderer() {
        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mrenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();

        double[] range = {0,5,0,5};

        mrenderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(16);
        mrenderer.setChartTitleTextSize(20);
         mrenderer.setLabelsTextSize(15);
         mrenderer.setLegendTextSize(15);
         mrenderer.setBarSpacing(0);
         mrenderer.setXLabels(1);
         mrenderer.addXTextLabel(2.5, "");
         mrenderer.setMargins(new int[] {20, 30, 15, 0});
         mrenderer.setAxesColor(Color.WHITE);
         mrenderer.setChartTitle("");
         mrenderer.setXTitle("");
         mrenderer.setInitialRange(range, 1);


         XYSeriesRenderer renderer1 = new XYSeriesRenderer();
         renderer1.setColor(Color.GREEN);
         XYSeriesRenderer renderer2 = new XYSeriesRenderer();
         renderer2.setColor(Color.GREEN);
         XYSeriesRenderer renderer3 = new XYSeriesRenderer();
         renderer3.setColor(Color.BLUE);


         mrenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer1);
         mrenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer2);
         mrenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer3);



          return mrenderer;

    }




}
```

**here is the xml file**

```
main.xml

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainActivity"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/graph2"
       android:layout_width="160dip"
        android:layout_height="200dip"
        android:scaleType="fitEnd"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="790dip"/>

  </RelativeLayout>
```

Try it !! Enjoyyy

Comment: Two among three bars are of one color and the last bar is of different color. They are not closer to each other. I have set spacing between them. But the bar's width is not adjustable.That's what I am worried about.

Comment: Don't just post code without explanation. Also, it's very poorly formatted.